# Using Select-String for checking two .txt files in powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line, select-string

I am complete new in writting powershell scripts. So far I was using plain batch for my purpose as this is the requirement by my company. Inside this batch I am using nested foor loops to make a comparison of two .txt files, in detail I wantdo do the following:

- File 1 contains lots of strings. Each string is in one seperate line with a preceded number and semicolon like so: `658;RMS`
- File 2 is some long text.

The aim is to count the amount of occurences of each string from File 1 in File 2, e.g. RMS is counted 300 times.

As my previous code hase some huge drawbacks concerning runtime (File 1 has approx. 400 lines and File 2 500.000) I read that the Select-String from Powershell is much more efficient.
However, as I am reading some tutorials it is not clear to me how I can proceed here, beside that I have to run the powershellcode inside my .bat. 
My biggest problem is I am not sure how and where to place my 'variables', so the two inputfiles 1 and 2

So far I was testing the Select-String method like this:

`powershell -command "& {Select-String -Path *.txt -Pattern "RMS"}"`

My assumption would be to make use of piping, so something like this:

`powershell -command "& {<<path to file one, should read line by line>> | Select-String -Path File2.txt -Pattern "value of file 1"}"`

However, I am not getting this to work. Powershell is excpecting some kind of `psobject` before the first pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For optimal performance, I would approach this task like so.

- Read the file with the terms as a CSV (it *is* a CSV, with a `;` delimiter)
- Read the other file into a string
- For each term, count how often it can be found in the target string (using `.IndexOf()`)

For example

```
$data = Import-Csv "file1.txt" -Delimiter ";" -Header ID,Term 
$target = Get-Content "file2.txt" -Raw
$counts = @{}

foreach ($term in $data.Term) {
    $index = -1
    $count = 0
    do {
        $index = $target.IndexOf($term, $index + 1)
        if ($index -gt -1) { $count++ } else { break; }
    } while ($true);
    $counts[$term] = $count
}

$counts
```

Notes

- `Import-Csv` will automatically use the first line in the input file as the header. If your file already has a header, you can remove the `-Headers` parameter.
- `Get-Content` will will read the input file into an array of lines by default. But for this approach, having the entire file as one big string is the right thing - that's what `-Raw` does.
- `@{}` creates an empty hashtable
- `$data.Term` will access one column of the CSV
- `.IndexOf()` is case sensitive. By default, PowerShell is case-insenstive, but native .NET methods like this one will not change their behavior. This might or might not be what you need - use `.ToLower()` on the `$target` and the `$term` if you don't care for case.

Comment: I tested your approach also and its quite fast :). is there some easy modification so it will only save those terms with a count higher than zero to $counts?
More, I have to modify the search expression with regular expressions so it only counts exact matches. As i am not familiar with powershell, where would be the right point to add this in your code?

Comment: *"is there some easy modification so it will only save those terms with a count higher than zero to `$counts`"* - Yes, there is, and I am sure you will find it. It's not difficult. :) -- *"I have to modify the search expression with regular expressions so it only counts exact matches."* - Huh? The above code does only count exact matches. Regular expressions are for situations where you *don't* want exact matches.

Comment: Oh okay I forgot to mention many sorry for this. In my file2 there are severla lines. For example I want to count the occurence of 'RM4'
Now there can exists the following lines:
123456789 RM4 987654321   -> should be counted as 1
However, the occurence in this line should not be counted:
12345 RM4.DLL  9876

So my aim was to capsulate the search term in white spaces so it is not followed by anything else :)

Comment: @SRel You can still do that. "Encapsulating the `$term` in spaces" is another super easy modification, but I'm not going to do it for you. I'm not trying to be difficult, but to encourage you to read the code I wrote and to understand what it does. Because as soon as you understand these few lines, you will know what to do. But if I make those changes, I'm not helping you understand.

Comment: Great I will try my best thank you for all your help, indeed that should be not so difficult

Comment: @SRel That's the spirit.

Comment: oh okay first thing was easy. I understood you code, very intelligent approach you did.
I now added  `if ($count -gt 0) {$counts[$term] = $count}`  and replaced `$counts[$term] = $count`  with this

Comment: i now have modified the answer from Mathias by adding a \s. However I am not sure where I can add a RegEx in your code. My other approach would be to just modify the searchterm by adding a whitespace at the end, would this be okay in this case?

Comment: @SRel Very good on the first point, that was exactly right. On the second point - you don't need regex. Just add a space `" "` to the front and back of `$term` and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

`Select-String` is *useful*, but it isn't magic :)

Performance impact in mind, I would approach it like this:

- For each line in `File2`:

  - Test for occurences of *all* terms in `File1`

This way, you only need to read and evalulate `File2` *once*:

```
# prepare hashtable to keep track of count
$count = @{}

# read terms to search for from file1
$termsToFind = Get-Content .\file1 |ForEach-Object {
  $_ -split ';' |Select -Last 1
}

# loop over lines in file2, count the words we're searching for
Get-Content .\test\file2 |ForEach-Object {
  foreach($term in $termsToFind){
    # Using `Regex.Matches()` will help us find multiple occurrences of the same term
    $count[$term] += [regex]::Matches($_,"\b$([regex]::Escape($term))\b").Count
  }
}
```

Now `$count` will be a hashtable where the key is the term from file1, and the value is the count of each word.

Output to the same format as `file1` with:

```
$count.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object { $_.Value,$_.Key -join ';' } |Set-Content output.txt
```

Comment: nice, but you forgot, that the content of `file1` is CSV-like `658;RMS` where he only needs the second column.

Comment: @T-Me thanks for spotting it, completely forgot that part :)

Comment: many thanks @MathiasR.Jessen I tested the first part where you read in file1 and this works perfectly fine. However trying to impement the second part reults in some rror cases. Did this occur beacuse I trying to fit the whole code in one line as I cannot run external powershell scripts? My code looks like this:

Comment: `powershell -command "& {$count = @{}; $termsToFind = Get-Content 'ModulID.txt' |ForEach-Object {$_ -split ';' |Select -Last 1}; Get-Content 'TlsTrace.prn' |ForEach-Object {foreach($term in $termsToFind){$count[$term] += [regex]::Matches($_,"\b$([regex]::Escape($term))\b").Count}}}"`
I changed the filenames to the real one, the other things are identical

Comment: I receive lot of `expressions missing`, however the first part is working

Comment: I'd strongly suggest either putting the code in a `.ps1` script file and then run `powershell -file C:\path\to\script.ps1`, or turning it into [an encoded command](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-encode-string-and-execute-with-powershell/)

Comment: Exclude the code in an exernal .ps1 script was my first intention, however running ps-scripts are blocked because of the policy and I am not able to override them :(
However, I can run simple PS-commands inside my batch, they are working

Comment: okay I wil try this. so the purpose of the encoded commands is to hide that batch is executing a ps-script?

Comment: @SRel No, the purpose is to be able to run a whole script as a one-liner without having to worry about escaping the input script on the command line - ie. exactly what you're struggling with :)

Comment: Ah thank you :) to now I am able to use the script inside a poweshell environment for testing and all seems to work. One last point as you are using regEx. My problem is that the exact phrase, e.g. `RM4` can also occur in the combination `RM4.dll, however the later one should not be counted. Is there some way to capsulate the search term for example in white spaces?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for your help. As both solutions are working I decided to mark  Tomalaks answer as it was a bit faster than yours. However many thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you check the docs, you can't pipe -pattern to select-string.  You can use parentheses to make the output of something become the pattern argument:

```
powershell select-string -pattern (get-content file1) -path file2
```

Using the fact that pattern is position 0 and path is position 1.  -pattern can also be an array.

```
powershell select-string (get-content file1) file2
```