# Get-Content -Raw alternative for older Shell

Tags: powershell, shell

According to my last question [Compare two Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62003411/using-select-string-for-checking-two-txt-files-in-powershell) I finally mentioned to get all to work inside my .bat. Thanks again for all the support.

However, as I find out today my supervisor is using Powershell in Version 2 instead of 5.1 than I do.
The problem now is that the `-Raw` paramterer of this code:

`$target = Get-Content "C:/pbr_tmp/PBreport/trc/TlsTrace.prn" -Raw` is not recognized.

Is there some alternative implementation instead of using -Raw?

Pupose of -Raw: The commands in this example get the contents of a file as one string, instead of an array of strings.

I am not sure If an upgrade from PS2 to PS5.1 is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using PowerShell version 2 you can use

```
 $target = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:/pbr_tmp/PBreport/trc/TlsTrace.prn")
```

From [SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html):

> -Raw
>         Return multiple lines as a single string (PowerShell 3.0)
>
> In PowerShell 2.0 use the static method: [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(string path)

Comment: perfect that worked fine.
However there are nwo some other lines which seems not be working correctly. I maybe have to completely switch
Do you see any command which can cause problems in PS2?

Comment: @SRel Glad to hear it helped. You should mark this as answer and then please post a separate question for your other issue. If you send me the link I will try to help!

Comment: Thanks @Bassie I asked a new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026711/conversion-from-powershell-v5-to-powershell-v2