# Conversion from Powershell V5 to Powershell V2

Tags: powershell, shell

According to my last question [Compare two Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62003411/using-select-string-for-checking-two-txt-files-in-powershell) I finally managed to get all to work inside my .bat. Thanks again for all your support.

However, as I find out today my supervisor is using Powershell in Version 2 instead of 5.1 than I do. The problem now is that the -Raw paramterer of this code:

```
$target = Get-Content "C:/pbr_tmp/PBreport/trc/TlsTrace.prn" -Raw
```

I changed this to:

```
$target = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:/pbr_tmp/PBreport/trc/TlsTrace.prn")
```

Unfortunately, the results are incorrect and I receive following error:

```
GetEnumerator : Fehler beim Aufrufen der Methode, da [System.Collections.DictionaryEntry] keine Methode mit dem Namen "GetEnumerator" enthält.
```

Does anyone know if there is something in the complete code snippet which can cause this?

```
$data = Import-Csv "C:/trc/ModulID.txt" -Delimiter ";" -Header ID,Term 
$target = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:/pbr_tmp/PBreport/trc/TlsTrace.prn")
$counts = @{}
foreach ($term in $data.Term) {
  $term = $term + " "
  $index = -1
  $count = 0
  do {
    $index = $target.IndexOf($term, $index + 1)
    if ($index -gt -1) { $count++ } else { break; }
  } while ($true);
  if ($count -gt 0) {$counts[$term] = $count}
 }
 $counts = $counts.GetEnumerator() | sort name
 $counts.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object {$_.Key, $_.Value -join '' } |Set-Content C:/pbr_tmp/PBreport/trace_results.txt
```

For example,

```
$counts = $counts.GetEnumerator() | sort name
```

Throws no exception.

Comment: For the love of everything holy, I implore you to abandon this wicked quest and help your supervisor upgrade Windows before an accident occurs ^_^

Comment: I will do so :) We are working in a sensitive environment, I am a bit nervous that installing .net framework may harm his PC. Or is my fear  Unjustified?

Comment: WMF 5.1 is _5 years old_ - if your manager is running Windows 7, _that_ should be your biggest worry :)

Answer (score 6):

Before jumping to the answer, let me just suggest one *actual solution*:

## Abandon PowerShell 2.0 ASAP!

It's old, it's slow, it doesn't have the nice features you're used to and it doesn't ship with the logging features that actually make PowerShell >5 what we might call a *securable* runtime.

If the choice of operating environment is not yours to influence, read ahead below

---

After the loop ends, `$counts` holds an object of type `[hashtable]`.

But after running this statement:

```
$counts = $counts.GetEnumerator() | sort name
```

`$counts` is no longer a `[hashtable]` - it's an array of individual key-value entries, as spat out by the enumerator.

So, to solve this, remove the `GetEnumerator()` call on `$counts` in the last statement:

```bsh
$counts = $counts.GetEnumerator() | sort name
$counts.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object {$_.Key, $_.Value -join '' } |Set-Content C:/pbr_tmp/PBreport/trace_results.txt
```

Comment: Thank you :) this works. However it seems that some behaviour of the commands has changed as the output only contains a number value. Before (running in PSV5) i received on the left the searchname and one the right the countvalue.
Maybe my only way is to install PS5 :)

Comment: It might be that `Key` on the key-value pairs is actually `Name` in 2.0, I'm afraid I don't have access to test that atm.